# .OVA File Compression for Distribution

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, compression, 7-zip

I created a virtual machine with that has a 4.7 GB virtual hard disk (.vmdk). I exported to .ova version 1.0 and got a 1.7 GB file which I was able to compress by another 200 mb using 7zip. So the 7zip archive with OVA is 1.5 GB.

7zipping the vm files directly gave me a file size of 1.1 GB. This is an ideal size and I'm wondering if anybody knows how to increase the compression of the ova file or manually create the ova file. I'm using virtual box but also have vmware. Here is the command I'm running on 7zip.

```
 7z a -t7z vm.7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa vm.ova
```

I'm running the same command without vm.ova inside the vm folder to get the 1.1 GB file. My goals are smallest file size and easily useable in both vmware and virtualbox, import to qemu, hyper-v, and vshere is a plus.

Comment: what happens if you shutdown the original VM, clone it first, then export without ever turning the clone on?  thoughts are to minimize any extraneous files (memory, log, etc) and also that you thin provisioned any virtual drives used.

Comment: Logs only add up to around 500 kb. I did clone then export for thoroughness, the exported .ova file was 1.7 GB as well. The drives are thin provisioned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `.ova` file is just a tar file according to the specs. Within the ova file is a `.vmdk` file which holds the virtual disk and a `.ovf` file which holds the configuration. OVF is a standard that works cross-platform.

After creating the ova file, extract the ovf and vmdk using tar

```
tar xvf appliance.ova
```

Delete the ova file or move it somewhere else if you need to.

The vmdk file is already compressed at this point so running 7zip directly on these two files won't reduce the compression by much.

Delete the .vmdk file and grab the original uncompressed vmdk file from before you made the appliance. Check your `.ovf` file (`xml`) to make sure the filenames match. Find the xml element that starts like this

```
<File ovf:href="diskname.vmdk" ovf:id="file1" />
```

In this case, the uncompressed vmdk file should be named (or renamed, if needed) to diskname.vmdk

Now run this 7zip command inside the directory with your 2 files (`.ovf` and `.vmdk`).

```
7z a -t7z appliance.7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa
```

Your `.7z` file can now be distributed with the smallest file size I was able to achieve.

To run the appliance just extract the files and import the `.ovf` file into VirtualBox, VMware or any other virtualization solution that can import appliances. As long as the two files are in the same directory it should import and run fine.

Comment: I tried several different methods and this is the one that worked best for me with the goal of having the smallest download size. manually creating the .ova file with tar and max gzip compression, compressing the ova file with 7zip, and creating the ova file with 7zip using the -tgzip switch. This created the smallest size but will create 2 copies of the uncompressed vmdk (once on extraction, once on import). after import, the extract files can be deleted though. An ova file might work best for simplicity if that is your goal.

Answer (score 4):

We found that zeroing out and then re-exporting from VirtualBox dramatically reduced the disk space of the ova. Went from 8.5 GB -> 3 GB.

1. Followed through step 2 of these instructions (https://www.howtogeek.com/312883/how-to-shrink-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-and-free-up-disk-space/)
2. Exported an new OVA from the VirtualBox GUI. (Am using 5.1.26 r117224 (Qt5.6.2) on a MacBook.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Zeroing out a vm drive is a basic step so I didn't mention it. Good tip for newbies though. The above steps produced the smallest file size on an optimized VM.

Comment: This answer is actually talking about `sdelete`.  For me personally, it reduced my ova from 13.7GB to 13.2GB.  See:  https://serverfault.com/a/165074